# sql server run remote job

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I need to manually run a job on more than 150 sql server instances (sql server 2000, remote) from a sql server 2005 instance (the local server). The job is the same on all these instances. The job just calls a stored procedure without parameter, which is also the same across all the instances. These jobs are on a schedule. But now they want me to manually run the job for all the instance or for specified instances upon request.

What is the best practice for this? I have tried openrowset to call the remote stored procedure. But each run of the job takes couple of minutes, so if I use a loop to run all these jobs, it will run one by one and that's a long time. Ideally, it should be able to run the stored procedure on each instance without waiting for it to finish. More ideally, it should be able to run the job on each instance without waiting for it to finish, so it can leave a record in the job history on each instance.

And the stored procedure is from a third party so it can't be altered.

update:

since the 'people' ask this to be initialised from a SSRS report, use SSRS to call some T-SQL/proc on the server would be most appropriate. The problem I got now is when calling msdb.dbo.sp_start_job on remote SQL Server 2000 instances from local server using OPENQUERY or OPENROWSET I got Cannot following error.

process the object "exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'xxx' ". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "xxx" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

I guess this may because the sp_start_job doesn't return anything because I can use OPENQUERY/OPENROWSET to call other remote proc without problem. So any workaround?

update:

I have found it actually pretty simple in t-sql.

EXEC [linkedServerName].msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'test2'

So I don't need to use OPENROWSET/OPENQUERY atually since all the remote SQL Server 2000 instances are already added as remote servers.

Comment: You might want to try posting this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndersUP  The link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37603/sql-server-2005-run-multiple-remote-jobs

Comment: Cool, looks as if you've got a couple of good answers there already.

Answer (score 1):

Is this actually a SQL Agent job that calls the procedure? If so you remotely call [sp_start_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) which will kick off the job asynchronously. I assume you're connecting as a sysadmin to do this.

If you had SQL Server 2008 client tools you could use "Local Server Groups". If you register all 150 SQL instances you can connect to them all at once by right-clicking the entire group and selecting "New Query". Down in the status bar you'll see it connect to 150/150 servers. Then whatever command you run it will run it on all 150 at the same time.

The servers don't have to be 2008, only your client tools. I routinely use this feature on SQL 2000 servers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it is a job calling a stored procedure. I am going to have a try.

Comment: Great, let us know if this did the trick.

Comment: I tried on SSMS 2008 and it works! But the SSMS 2008 is what I installed for testing purpose. The production server is 2005 and the SSMS 2005 can't issue query for the group (I am wondering what's the use of registered servers then). They (actually some supporting people) want this to be some kind of function so that they can use it by themselves. So what can I do? I can't let them install SQL Server 2008 apparently.

Comment: And I need to parametrize this function so that they can select whatever instances to run the job.

Comment: You'll probably want to stick with the original idea of running a cursor to execute sp_start_job then. You could create a procedure that accepts a table-valued parameter of server names, then create a cursor that loops through them and remotely calls sp_start_job using OPENROWSET. That of course assumes you don't want to use any outside utilities like PowerShell or the like.

Comment: Yes, my first try was to use OPENROWSET. But I have some problem with that too. I will update when I work this out. Thanks.